# SBT evalute an InputTask even when I have un-matched condition to run it

Tags: sbt

This is the code I have:

```
run in Compile := { true match {
    case true => (run in Compile).evaluated
    case false => (run in Compile).evaluated
}}
```

And output:

```
> run
[info] Running Main 
[info] Running Main 
Main.main
Main.main
```

I expect that `SBT` evaluate the `(run in Compile)` just once! but it run it twice! why! Am I missing something?

Comment: Interesting! I don't know input tasks too well, but thinking that `.value` and `.evaluated` are similiar I would've expected the same.

Comment: @DaleWijnand `.value` is depricated on `0.13` and removed on `1.x`; alternatives are `evaluated` and `inputTaskValue`.

Comment: Right I meant `.evaluated` on `InputKey` is similar to `.value` on `SettingKey` and `TaskKey`. But it looks like there are ways in which it's not.

Comment: I think this is a bug... it’s difficult for me to believe that sbt can't possibly cache the parser wrapping the input task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistak! the macros behavior is right! I must used `taskDyn` to define my task: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html#Dynamic+Computations+with